# Compare two texts accurately

Tags: linux, awk, diff, redhat

dear friend

Now I am finding a terminal to compare two texts accurately.

Please check the below details first

**The first text**

```
111  222  name1
111  555  sea1
```

**The second text**

```
777  888  blue1
111  666  name1
```

**The final result**

```
Updated:"111 666 name1" 

New Added:"777 888 blue1" 

New Deleted:"111 555 sea1"
```

First,We should compare the 3rd column of two texts.you could find that the "name1" in two texts are the same.

Based on this,we start to compare the 1st column and the 2nd column of "name1" line to find the different.But,the 1st and the 2nd column should be as one part to compare,not two parts

If it exist the different in the second text,it would print the final result

```
Updated:"111 666 name1"
```

Second,if the name of the 3rd column only exsit in the 2rd text,it would print the final result

```
New Added:"777 888 blue1"
```

Third,if the name of the 3rd column only exist in the 1st text,please print the final result

```
New Deleted:"111 555 sea1"
```

If possible,Please give me more guidances about this

Thank you so much

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: are  you aware of the standard utility `diff file1 file2` ? It produces similar, but less verbose output. Good luck.

Comment: For me,the biggest obstacle is if we want to achieve this ,it should be combine the diff and awk,or other.But I had test and research for long time.The final result is not very satisfied

Comment: You need to tell us why you want to do this (maybe you have a good reason, but you haven't shared it with us). Becuase I don't know what you're trying to solve, based on my experience making diff views, my advise is to learn to use and understand the output from `diff`. If you really need more advanced marking of differences, then you have to write a specification more precise than above, construct tests for each case in the specification and then try to solve each test case separately, and then merge your solutions.OR use a database, it may be easier to write a diff w rules there. Good luck!

Comment: @sheltler 
I had checked the webpage:https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib-interface.

The first biggest obstacle:

eg.The old text is "111  222  name1", The new text is "111  666  name1",
**The same part - "name1"**
**The different part - "111 222" is changed to the "111 222"**             
**Now by the terminal or python script could show the different.BUT How to but filter the result.**
**1.someone only show in the new text.
2.someone had showed in the old text,but it has a little new changes in the new text**

If possible,please give me some guidances about how to filter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started. Save the program to **diff.awk**

```
# Usage:
# awk -f diff.awk old.txt new.txt 

function trim(s) { # remove trailing spaces
    sub("[[:space:]]+$", "", s)
    return s
}

function decode() { # sets `key', `val', and `all'
    all = $0
    key = $3; $3 = ""
    val = trim($0)
}

FNR != NR {
    file = 1
}

file == 0 { # old file
    decode()

    keys[n++] = key
    vals[key] = val
    alls[key] = all
}

file == 1 { # new file
    decode()

    if (!(key in vals))
        printf "New Added:\"%s\"\n", all
    else if (all != alls[key]) {
        printf "Updated:\"%s\"\n", all
        delete vals[key] # seen this key in new file
    }
}

END {
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        key = keys[i]
        if (key in vals)
           printf "New Deleted:\"%s\"\n", alls[key]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello,dear slitvinov,that is so graeat ,thank you so much again.I am also learning the knowledge about the AWK,it is so powerful.